# compare two dictionaries of different keys in python

Tags: python

How can I compare two dictionaries of different keys, such as the ones below?

```
dictionary={"name":"abc","age":23,"male":True}
new_dictionary={"my_name":"abc","my_age":23,"male":1}
```

When the two dictionaries in the example are compared, the comparison should return `true`.

Comment: By what criteria are these the same?

Comment: You'll have to do some good ole item by item comparison.

Comment: Explain to us, how do you want to compare them.

Comment: You need to define a mapping from old key name to new key name. But I notice that you also have changed the type of the value associated with 'male' from boolean to integer, so you may also need to specify how to convert from one type to another.

Comment: This looks like it needs NLP on thy keys to determine synonymity.

Comment: the values will be same for example name is abc in both dict and age is same in both dict

Comment: @Alex, `1 == True` so you actually don't need to do any type conversion there.

Comment: @user1018828: please update your question; the answers below are all guessing at what you meant at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> dictionary={"name":"abc","age":23,"male":True}
>>> new_dictionary={"my_name":"abc","my_age":23,"male":1}
>>> key_map = {"name": "my_name", "age": "my_age"}
>>> all(new_dictionary[key_map.get(k, k)] == v for k, v in dictionary.items())
True
```

Or if you are just interested in ensuring that the values are the same without any key checking:

```
>>> set(dictionary.values()) == set(new_dictionary.values())
True
```

**edit:** As Tadeck pointed out in comments, `sorted()` is safer to use here than `set()`.

(Yes, this works even though one dictionary has `1` and the other has `True`)

Comment: I also was thinking initially about using `set()`s, but I came out with the conclusion, that `{"a": 1, "b": 1, "c": 2}` will be equal to `{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 2}` if compared that way. I suppose this is not it, thus I switched to using `sorted(dict.values())` comparison for both dicts.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define the exact way the comparison happens. If you want to just compare the values, regardless of the keys they are assigned to, you can use this:

### Comparing by values (ignoring the keys)

One of the solutions, based on your updated requirements, is:

```
>>> def compare(dict1, dict2):
    return sorted(dict1.values()) == sorted(dict2.values())

>>> compare({"name":"abc","age":23,"male":True},
    {"my_name":"abc","my_age":23,"male":1})
True
>>> compare({"name":"abc","age":23,"male":True},
    {"my_name":"abc","my_age":24,"male":1})
False
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dictionary={"name":"abc","age":23,"male":True}
new_dictionary={"my_name":"abc","my_age":23,"male":1}    
dict_alias = {"name":"my_name","age":"my_age","male":"male"}

def compare(dictionary,new_dictionary,dict_alias):
    same = True
    for key in dictionary.keys():
        if dictionary[key] == new_dictionary[dict_alias[key]]:
            continue
        else:
            same = False
            break
    return same
```